# useEffect Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't find any reason for why my code is acting this way. I have 2 JSX components that implement state and the useEffect function. One of the components triggers useEffect, the other doesn't. I've defined state and useEffect the same way in both files, as well. Would appreciate any help with this

`reviewDeckRoute.jsx` (does not trigger useEffect)

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import FlashcardParent from '../flashcard/flashcardParent'

const ReviewDeckRoute = ({deckID}) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/deck/' + deckID

    const [deckInfo, setDeckInfo] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("CALLED API")
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            setDeckInfo(response.data)
        })
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <h1>Review Flashcards</h1>
            <FlashcardParent deckInfo={deckInfo} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReviewDeckRoute;
```

`editDeckRoute.jsx` (triggers useEffect)

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import EditFlashcard from "../editFlashcard/editFlashcard"

const EditDeckRoute = ({deckID}) => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/deck/" + deckID
    
    const [deckInfo, setDeckInfo] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            setDeckInfo(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    function newCard() {
        const tmpDeck = new Map()
        tmpDeck.set("topic", "")
        tmpDeck.set("description", "")
        tmpDeck.set("id", deckInfo.length++)

        // create brand new array. loop through deckInfo and add elements to new array
        let tmpArr = []
        deckInfo.map((card) => {
            tmpArr.push(card)
        })
        tmpArr.push(tmpDeck)

        setDeckInfo(tmpArr)
    }

    function handleDeckInfoChange(index, e) {
        console.log(`${[e.target.name]}: ${e.target.value} ${index} `)
        setDeckInfo(prevState => ({
            ...prevState.map(card => ({
                ...card = new Map(Object.entries(card)),
                ...card.get("id") === index
                ? card.set([e.target.name], e.target.value)
                : card
            }))
        }))
    }

    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Edit Flashcards</h1>
                    <button onClick={newCard} >Add Card</button>
                </div>
                {deckInfo.map((flaschard, num) => {
                        return <EditFlashcard key={num} index={num} flaschard={flaschard} change={handleDeckInfoChange} />
                    }
                )}

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditDeckRoute;
```

Comment: I think you should add the URL in the dependency array of the `useEffect` in `reviewDeckRoute.jsx`.

Comment: Maybe you mean to say, the component is not re-rendered, rather than saying it is not triggered. useEffect always executes at least once. You need to pass the `deckID` as a dependency if you want a re-render.

Comment: @Ergis it truly doesn't seem to get called. 2 reasons that i'm saying this. 1) I have my server log whenever it gets receives a request. It never logs anything when I go to the reviewDeckRoute, whereas it does when I go to the editDeckRoute. Both routes even make a request to the same endpoint. 2) After going to the reviewDeckRoute, there is never anything in the console, even though I explicitly have it `console.log("CALLED API")`

Comment: @MohamedSayed even that doesn't seem to do it, strangely enough

Answer (score 0):

Edit the non-working component useEffect to be:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CALLED API")
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setDeckInfo(response.data)
    })
}, [deckID])
```

Now the useEffect has a dependency on deckID, so when deckID changes, it will re-trigger the useEffect with new information. If you leave the dependency array empty, it triggers only on the initial first render.

(this is assuming you can render the component and are on the correct route)

Comment: sorta figured out the issue.`editDeckRoute` renders twice. First render doesn't make an http request, but the 2nd time, it does. no clue why it's working that way. After trying to read from `deckInfo` after the first render in the `FlashcardParent` component, i would get an error since there was no data to read